# MySQL - how to get NULL from `SELECT IF(NULL, 2, 3)`

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using mysql function `if`.
When I run `SELECT IF(NULL, 2, 3)`, I got `3`.

can I get NULL when first argument is NULL by changing this SQL?

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_if.asp

Comment: `null` is unknown. You need special functions and operator to compare to `null`

Comment: I prefer coalesce https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `IF()` combined with `ISNULL()`:

```sql
SELECT IF(ISNULL(NULL), 2, 3)  -- output is 2
```